# Huawei Ascend P1 U9200: upgrading (International to Chinese)

Tags: updates, stock-android, huawei

I own a **Huawei Ascend P1** smartphone (**U9200, unlocked, international version**, still original Android 4.0.3 factory build B003). During about a year that I have the phone, it started being **much slower** and I decided that it's time to upgrade the software. I have the following question:

Is it safe to try to **upgrade** an *international P1* to more modern P1 firmware, but focused on Chinese market? The only official release available for my phone is Jelly Bean with EMUI 1.5, which is pretty old (B315, URL is available). I was hoping to upgrade, at least, to this Chinese release (B709): http://en.club.vmall.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=15972&extra=page%3D2. Also, it would be nice to read about any experiences, especially regarding feature set and stability, on the above, as well as (just in case) recommendations on restoring back official manufacturer's firmware for international models from Chinese firmware releases.

**Your advice will be very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same build. I went up to the Chinese B710 that have the most features including the radio and HDMI.  Google apps is not on B710 firmware and instead the Chinese version of it. I decided to roll back to B315 without radio and HDMI (not without, but with no sound). B315 is OK (the sound is now extra loud, they must have activated that dolby sound at last), there are minor things that is not there anymore, eg the wallpapers don't scroll anymore, but it's still way better than ICS.

To go from B315 to B710 uses the same intermediate pack found on Huawei.com (Click on Emui and look for P1).
The Chinese version is all in Chinese obviously and the phone is packed with Chinese apps that can not be de-installed. If you have a large memory card you could hide all the icons in there and download apps from the internet although it is much more of a hassle. I was unsuccessful in installing Google Playstore and it can't replace the default Chinese version.

The perfect scenario would be to get B710 Global version with Google apps, radio and HDMI, but this does not exist. (Did some extensive research on the net, nothing.) I would't even bother with the KitKat and fake Lollipop stuff on the net. You basically have the options of B229 ICS with everything but fewer features, or Jellybean B315 with some stuff removed from B229 and lots of extra other stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (+1)! I also did quite a bit of research on the subject and agree with your insights. I am thinking about MIUI (don't confuse with EMUI), which has several firmware distributions for P1 to choose from. The standard one is this: http://en.miui.com.

Answer (score 1):

i just installed the official firmware.(B315, Jellybean) If you don't use the radio and MHL capabilities it is worth it, as those are not on there. Makes the phone faster, improves the camera. Battery icon shows exact percentage battery remaining making it at least feel if it last longer, still won't last the entire day if gaming on it. The volume up takes a photo and feels more responsive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion! Have you upgraded from the same build that I have (B003)? Have you tried or thought about trying other firmware options, for example Chinese market EMUI or MIUI firmware? Thanks again.